# Может ли быть ключом нехэшируемый объект?

Tags: python, python-3.x

В учебниках пишут, что ключами словаря могут быть только неизменяемые объекты (кортежи, строки, числа и т.д.), неизменяемые типы имеют хеш.

В отличие от встроенных типов, пользовательские типы (то есть классы) изменяемы, поэтому они не имеют хеша. Но можно в них реализовать методы `__hash__()` и `__eq__()`. После этого они станут хешируемыми. Я думаю, что в этом случае их можно будет использовать в качестве ключей в словаре.

Вот пример:

```
#!/usr/local/lib/python3

class w():
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x

  def __hash__(self):
    return True

  def __eq__(self, y):
    return False

ww = w(12)

print(ww)
print(hash(ww))

q = {
  ww: 333,
  1: 'qwe',
  'qqq': 'asd',
  (1, 2): 'zxc'
}

print(q['qqq'])
print(q[ww])
```

В результате я в выводе получаю хеш:

```
<__main__.w object at 0x7f01fb162b38>
-9223363308949511501
asd
333
```

Проблема в том, что если закомментировать методы `__hash__()` и `__eq__()`, то экземпляр всё равно подходит для использования в качестве ключа:

```
class w():
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x

  # def __hash__(self):
  #   return True

  # def __eq__(self, y):
  #   return False

ww = w(12)

print(ww)
print(hash(ww))

q = {
  ww: 333,
  1: 'qwe',
  'qqq': 'asd',
  (1, 2): 'zxc'
}

print(q['qqq'])
print(q[ww])
```

Потому, что вывод в консоль остаётся таким же.

[LIVE DEMO здесь](https://ideone.com/epohOw)

Comment: Скорее всего `hash` может у любого объекта взять хеш, например по его `id`, просто изменяемые коллекции (list, dict, и т.п.) специально ругаются в своем магическом методе `def __hash__(self)`

Comment: Если изменить ключ, хеш тоже измениться, как после изменения получить значение по ключу?

Comment: а если я в __hash__буду возвращать константу? нет, не венрю, что питон не будет бросать искллючение при использовании неизменяемого объекта и оставит отлов ткаих ошибок разработчику. что-то я не понимаю

Comment: Что касается хэша, то критически важным является только то, чтобы для каждого объекта его хэш оставался неизменным в течении всего времени работы программы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В отличие от встроенных типов, пользовательские типы (то есть классы) изменяемы, поэтому они не имеют хеша.

Это не так. В третьем питоне все пользовательские классы неявно наследуются от типа object, для которого хэширование и эквивалентность реализованы. Соответственно, для любого пользовательского класса хэширование и эквивалентность тоже будут реализованы, даже если не определены явно.

При использовании пользовательских классов в качестве ключа нужно просто очень ясно понимать, что в данном случае является хэшом и эквивалентностью.

Например, для экземпляра класса с унаследованной от object эквивалентностью, для экземпляра эквивалентным будет считаться только сам этот экземпляр. Если вы создадите другой экземпляр, передав в конструктор точно такие же аргументы, то этот новый экземпляр всё равно не будет считаться эквивалентным.

Comment: Значит использовать пользовательские классы как ключи технически возможно. но не надёжно и  за последствия будет отвечать разработчик?

Comment: @rettoryh13, просто важно ясно понимать, что именно в каждом конкретном случае является эквивалентностью.